# Cocos2D 2.x - getting framerate_ value from CCDirector

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use the ivar 'framerate_' value calculated in the 'showStats' method in the CCDirector class. At the moment I've added a method to the CCDirector.m/h files to access the value e.g....

CCDirecor.h:

```
-(ccTime)getCCFrameRate;
```

CCDirecor.m:

```
-(ccTime)getCCFrameRate {
    return frameRate_;
}
```

...so I can now get the value like so:

```
ccTime frameRateOutput = [[MyDirector sharedDirector] getCCFrameRate];
```

This works but I would prefer to not 'hack' the Cocos2D framework code. I've tried subclassing CCDirector but I ran into a few problems. Appreciate any advice on the best approach to get this 'framerate_' ivar without messing with the framework code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get any ivar of any object like this:

```
Ivar iv = object_getInstanceVariable(obj, "_framerate");
void *ivp = (char *)obj + ivar_getOffset(iv);
TYPE framerate = *(TYPE *)ivp;
```

However, in my opinion, this is even more of a hack than extending the framework.

Comment: Thanks, that's handy to know... but I also agree it's a bit hack-ish. I think I will leave the edits to CCDirector I have made. If I ever have to update the framework, I guess my custom created method should at least come up as a trackable error if I forget to reapply it.eg 'cant find method 'getCCFrameRate' on CCDirector etc.

Comment: @staticfiction or you can use version control... Use git, really.

Answer (score 1):

You could reproduce the same code in a custom class, if you absolutely want to avoid modifying the CCDirector code.

Although the latter is absolutely ok, you'll only ever have an issue with that if you upgrade to a newer cocos2d version. In that case just reapply your changes, since they're so minimal.

You can't easily subclass CCDirector because it's a singleton and it already has platform specific subclasses CCDirectorIOS and CCDirectorMac.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned in my comment on H2CO3. I think I will leave my edits to CCDirector. Good to be reassured that the approach will not likely cause any unforseen problems though.